# Flexbox rearrange vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

and flexbox gurus,

I'm becoming desperate finding an elegant solution (= without having to add additional container- / wrapper elements) for the following problem:

The (simplified) HTML looks like:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__header">
    <span>(( Title ))</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card__visual">
    (( image ))
  </div>
  <div class="card__body">
    <p>(( some text ))</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and respective SCSS:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  &__header {
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  &__visual {
    background: deepskyblue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    ...
  }
  &__body {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

This results - as expected - as follows:

[image: Figure1]

So far so good, this is what it should look on mobiles.
The problem & question is, how the same HTML structure could be styled to get the following output:

[image: Figure1]

Is there even a way to achieve this? The most close I could come so far is:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  &__header {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
    ...
  }
  &__visual {
    align-self: flex-start;
    width: 49%;
    ...
  }
  &__body {
    align-self: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
    ...
  }
}
```

But I cannot find a way to eliminate the "gap" between the header and body:

[image]

So anyone out here with a smart approach :) ? Inputs warmly appreciated.

Comment: Essentially, you can't without a wrapper (or a fixed height) , that's not the way flexbox works. CSS-Grid would be a better option.

Comment: @Paulie_D - thanks a lot! I was - of course - searching on SO but did obviously not find the right terms...